# Understanding static routes

Tags: routing

I have seen this static route in one of the interfaces of the router:

```
ip route vrf vrf_45065 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 172.22.145.153 2
ip route vrf vrf_45065 10.158.138.192 255.255.255.192 172.22.145.153 2
```

Why use  `1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 172.22.145.153 2`  at all ?

Comment: Do you refer to the "2" at the end of the line?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The route

```
ip route vrf vrf_45065 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 172.22.145.153 2
```

Is often called a host route.  It means that traffic to the address 1.1.1.1 (only) will be forwarded to 172.22.145.153.  The administrative distance for this route is set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned static route is  VRF Configured virtual route forward . VRF Actually Configured on layer3 devices creating virtual instance creating separate routing table for this VRF .

`ip route vrf vrf_45065 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 172.22.145.153 2`

Above static route is configured for routing traffic to specific /32 subnet ,traffic with destination ip address 1.1.1 .1 is routed towards next hop interfàce 172.2#.145.153 .
2 = AD value . By default static route AD value is 1 . We have feasibility to change AD value accordinglly to our requirements . When two route are configured to same destination layer3 devices will give priority and picks lowest Configured AD value route